# The beforeunload event was not triggered when not on the site's page

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events, onbeforeunload, unmount

I have an event that needs to indicate if the user `is_online` or not. I'm using the `beforeunload` event, which triggering when the page is closed, and when it trigger I put the `is_online` property to `false`

Its works good when I close the page directly. However, when I skip to another tab in my browser and wait couple of minutes and then I close the page, this event didn't triggered and my user `is_online` status still appears as `true`.

this is the relevant code:

```
window.addEventListener(
    "beforeunload",
    async (event) => {
      event.stopImmediatePropagation();
      await set_user_is_online({value:false});
    },
    { once: true }
  );
```

Comment: Check out the `visibilitychange` event instead. See https://www.igvita.com/2015/11/20/dont-lose-user-and-app-state-use-page-visibility/